# How to use LIS to solve 10635 uva

Tags: algorithm, lcs

How to do the reduction from Longest Common Subsequence to O(nlog n) Longest Increasing Subsequence for the problem [10635 uva](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&category=&problem=1576&mosmsg=Submission%20received%20with%20ID%2010145813). I need some help regarding the logic to be applied to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

For each step of the route of one of the two characters(let's say the princess), assign the number of this step in the sequence of the prince.

First observation - all the steps not present in the prince's sequence are immediately removed - they can not be part of the common sequence of moves.

Now we have a sequence of numbers representing the index in the sequence of moves of the prince. We should choose an increasing subsequence(increasing because we should visit the cells in the same order as the prince) of maximal length of that sequence. Ringing any bells?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would be grateful if you give a more precise and clear definition of what you mean by "assign the number of this step in the sequence of the prince" in the first line of your reply.

Comment: The path of each character is an array where you have the cell visited on the given step. So You hve this array for the prince and you go through the cells of the princess and for each cell present in the array of the prince, you assign the index of this cell in the prince array, you dicard the cells that are not present in the prince's array. Now you need to do LIS on the numbers you got (i.e. the indecies). Hope this makes it more clear.

Comment: if for each element of princess array we find the corresponding element in prince array this becomes a O(nm) algorithm. Which defeats the purpose of using O(nlog n) LIS for this question. I understood what you have mentioned in your post and even implemented the same and got TLE :( . Correct me if I am wrong at any place or does any other method exists to solve the question.

Comment: You are wrong in your understanding. You can do the first part in linear time with respect to the number of cells in the grid(which is the upper limit of the common path lenght so no better solution can exist). Create an array of size n*n and assigne -1 to each value. Then for each cell in the prince's path change the value for that cell to be the index in his path. Now having this array you can process each cell of the princess' path in contant time. Does that make sense?